# Basemap - draw points on map depending on coordinates; dot size = number of occurences

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib-basemap

I have a dataset like the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({
    # some ways to create random data
    'Name of City':np.random.choice(["City A", 'City B', 'City C', "City D", "City E", "City F", "City G"], 22),
    'Name of Country':np.random.choice(["Country A", "Country B", "Country C"], 22),
    'lat':np.random.choice([-41, -20, 1, 19, 34, 66, 81], 22),
    'lon': np.random.choice([- 10, 10, 4, 1, -20, 60, 0], 22)
    })
```

where the lat/ lon denotes coordinates and the name of the city denotes the belonging city.

I would like to plot the city coordinates on a world map using the coordinates - with the dot size depending on the number of ocurrences of this city in my data set but don't know how to best go about it.

Based on this code

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    x, y = row[['lon','lat']]
    plt.annotate(
        str(idx), 
        xy = (x, y), xytext = (-20, 20),
        textcoords = 'offset points', ha = 'right', va = 'bottom',
        bbox = dict(boxstyle = 'round,pad=0.5', fc = 'yellow', alpha = 0.5),
        arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '->', connectionstyle = 'arc3,rad=0'))

plt.show()
```

I managed to plot the dots somehow but cannot figure out how to put them on a map. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not quite clear on how your coordinates should relate to your city names, but assumed that the same coordinate pair should be used for each time a certain city is mentioned. Based on this I took a little bit of freedom how to generate a database that fulfils these requirements and how to extract data from it. The rest is more or less straight forward using `Basemap`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits import basemap

cities = pd.DataFrame({
    'city': ["City A", 'City B', 'City C', "City D", "City E", "City F", "City G"],
    'lat': [-41, -20, 1, 19, 34, 66, 81],
    'lon': [- 10, 10, 4, 1, -20, 60, 0],
})
print(cities)

choices = np.random.choice(range(len(cities.lat)),22)
print(choices)

counts = np.array([list(choices).count(i) for i in range(len(cities.lat))])
print(counts)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
bmap = basemap.Basemap(ax = ax)

bmap.drawcountries()
bmap.drawcoastlines()

x,y = bmap(cities.lon, cities.lat)

ax.scatter(x, y, s=(2*counts)**2, c='r', label=cities.city)

for idx, row in cities.iterrows():
    x, y = bmap(*row[['lon','lat']])
    plt.annotate(
        str(idx), 
        xy = (x, y), xytext = (-20, 20),
        textcoords = 'offset points', ha = 'right', va = 'bottom',
        bbox = dict(boxstyle = 'round,pad=0.5', fc = 'yellow', alpha = 0.5),
        arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '->', connectionstyle = 'arc3,rad=0'))


plt.show()
```

The resulting image looks something like this:

[image]